# Use multi-character delimiter in Amazon Redshift COPY command

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, character-encoding, amazon-redshift, delimiter

I am trying to load a data file which has a multi-character delimeter('|~|') to Amazon Redshift DB using the COPY command. Redshift COPY command does not allow for multi-character delimiters.

My data looks like this -

```
John|~|23|~|Los Angeles|~|USA
Jade|~|27|~|New York|~|USA
```

When I try to use multi-characters in the COPY command I get "COPY delimiter must be a single character;" error.

My COPY command looks like this -

```
copy test_data from 's3://abcd/testFile' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<redacted>;aws_secret_access_key=<redacted>' 
delimiter '|~|' 
null as '\0'
acceptinvchars
ignoreheader as 1
MAXERROR 1;
```

I cannot replace or edit the source files since they are very large(>100GB), so I need a solution within the AWS Redshift paradigm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't edit the source files, and you can't use a multi-character delimiter, then use `|` as the delimiter and add additional (fake) columns that will be loaded with `~`.

You can then either ignore these columns, or use `CREATE TABLE AS` to copy the data to a new table but without those columns.

Or, use `CREATE VIEW` to make a version of that table without the fake columns.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this approach but some of the columns have '|' as a character. That breaks the script because it's also a delimiter. That is part of the reason I posted the question.

Comment: Then the only alternative (aside from editing the source files before loading) is to load the entire line as one field (no delimiter), then copy the data to a new table using [SPLIT_PART Function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) to split on the multi-character delimiter.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I wonder if the performance would be reasonable for over 600 million rows? It's a DC2 cluster with 4 nodes.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion.I created a table with a single column(VARCHAR(MAX)), removed the "delimiter" option from the COPY command but I'm getting Err 1202 "Extra columns found". I would think it would not look for extra columns at all.  Any clues as to what's happening?

Comment: It is probably defaulting to `|`. Set the delimiter to `\001` (Ctrl-A) or any other character that isn't used, then try loading again. The performance should be reasonably good, since all data is already in Redshift and it will run in parallel. Main thing is to make sure it has enough free disk space.